# How to measure the depth from disparity map?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have an disparity map then I want to measure the depth from the disparity map.

I use this code

```
 pointsd = PointCollection.ReprojectImageTo3D(disparity, Q);
```

The output is x:-42.92741  y:-24.21322  z:10000 ,but I want to get the output in cm.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The distance would be euclidean distance from this point to left camera ( if you used stereo camera ).Since, the left camera is origin of your coordinate system the distance would be √(x^2+y^2+z^2 ). The result would be in the same unit that you specified for your square size while calibrating your camera using the chessboard means if you gave the side in mm ,cm or m the resulting distance would be in mm , cm , m respectively.